# Assign name to query temporarily

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a mechanism in T-SQL that allows one to name a query temporarily?

Specifically I would like to be able to do this without using stored procedures, as these will ultimately be one-offs, and I'd like them to not exist after the end of the batch.

Something like,

```
/* this is woefully invalid syntax */
DECLARE @reps = SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Representatives

SELECT * FROM OtherTable 
WHERE RepName not in @reps
```

Comment: If views are an option that's one way to go. You can also create a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you may be looking for some Dynamic SQL

```
Declare @Reps varchar(max) = 'Select Distinct [Name] FROM Representatives'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select * From OtherTable Where RepName not in ('+@Reps+')'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Another option would be to create a Table Variable

```
Declare @Reps table (Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @Reps Select Distinct Name From Representatives

Select * 
 From  OtherTable
 Where RepName not in (Select * From @Reps)
```

Comment: The table variable does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Depending on your purposes and how many rows you're using, a temp table might be better. Table Variables are assumed by the optimizer to have one row by default so work better with smaller data sets. Temp Tables can have stats and more indexes. Syntax is similar: CREATE TABLE #MyTable (MyName varchar(50)) and SELECT * FROM #MyTable.

Comment: @PeterSchott  100% agreement.  I'm the first to say THERE IS NO SHAME IN USING TEMP TABLES.

Comment: Well, there _can_ be, but it's rare. Worst example I saw was when people would build temp tables like scratch work, sometimes adding a column based on columns from the last temp table or worst, a static column. Ended up with 10-15 temp tables instead of 3-4.